# Needle is not updating when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a svg of thermometer and I want some kind of interaction with it. The interaction will be, to move the needle as per the value provided by user. The value can be provided from the ranger and the thermometer should be updated by moving the needle.

I have created an example in webpack bin so you can see the demo over here https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Khv7qwzOc5OlYE9UY-1

Here is what i have done

```js
componentDidMount(){
  this.animationH.setAttribute('from', this.animationH.getAttribute('to'));
  this.animationH.setAttribute('to', this.state.value);
  this.animationY.setAttribute('from', this.animationY.getAttribute('to'));
  this.animationY.setAttribute('to', this.state.value);
}

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}

render() {
  const {value} = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="range" 
        min="1" 
        max="100" 
        step="1" 
        onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
      />
      {value ? value : ''}
      <svg width="133px" height="350px" viewBox="0 0 133 1113" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect id="Rectangle-2" stroke="#979797" strokeWidth="2.132" fill="#C20C0C" filter="url(#filter-1)" x="56.8899994" y="735" width="18" height="200">
        <animate 
          attributeName="height"
          from="0"
          to="200"
          fill="freeze"
          dur="2s"
          ref={(animationH) => this.animationH = animationH}
        />
        <animate 
          attributeName="y"
          from="935"
          to="735"
          fill="freeze"
          dur="2s"
          ref={(animationY) => this.animationY = animationY}
        />
        </rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not updating because you set the `height` and `y` values of the `<rect>` through the animations, which are triggered in `componentWillMount`. You have two options for how to solve this:

## 1. Trigger animation on change

Extract the code in `componentWillMount` to a new method, `animate`, and call it when changing values:

```js
// In your component

componentWillMount() {
  this.animate();
}

animate() {
  this.animationH.setAttribute('from', this.animationH.getAttribute('to'));
  this.animationH.setAttribute('to', this.state.value);
  this.animationY.setAttribute('from', this.animationY.getAttribute('to'));
  this.animationY.setAttribute('to', this.state.value);
}

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value }, this.animate.bind(this));
  // 2nd argument is a callback, called after setState is complete (it is potentially async)
}
```

## 2. Use CSS transitions instead of triggering animations

Don't use SVG animations, just use the value(s) from state to set properties to the rect inside the `render`-method and apply CSS transitions to `height` and `y`. Then you will automatically render correct value after you `setState`.

Working example: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ki4KIR0eSLQrGh2JrAz

```js
// In your component

render() {
  return (
    ...
      <rect
        className="temperature-bar"
        stroke="#979797"
        strokeWidth="2.132"
        fill="#C20C0C"
        filter="url(#filter-1)"
        x="56.8899994"
        y={value}
        width="18"
        height={value}>
    ...
  );
}
```

```
// CSS for your component

rect.temperature-bar {
  transition-property: y, height;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

## I would suggest

I would suggest the second approach whenever possible, because it follows the core idea behind React: to always render based on state/props (and not mutate the DOM outside the render method like you are doing when triggering the animations).

PS: You need to properly calculate `y` and `height` for the rect, because now it turns out completely wrong, but you probably knew that.